# Is [K(x):E] finite when E is an intermediate field between K and K(x)?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $K$ be a field and let $K\subsetneq E \subseteq K(x) $. Is it true that $[K(x):E]<\infty$?

For some context, this is a follow up question in Hungerford's Algebra, exercise V.2.6 (a), after proving that for relatively prime and non constant $f,g \in K[x]$, we have $[K(x):K(f/g)]=\max\{\deg f, \deg g\}<\infty$. It seems to me that this is true when $K(f/g)\subseteq E$, but if it's not, then I don't really know how to proceed. Anyone care to help me?

Comment: Is $\;x\;$ a transcendental element over $\;E\;$ ?

Comment: It is true but is equivalent to what you are asked to prove in the exercise. Try to see if you could express $x$ as a root of a polynomial using coefficients  from $K$ and $f/g$. As long as you can find one, you are done.

Comment: That's question (a) in the exercise. $x$ is the root of the polynomial $\phi(y)=(f(x)/(g(x))g(y)-f(y)$. My question is in part (b) of the exercise. Do you mean (a) will imply (b)?

Comment: Yes. Because as you said, if $K(f/g)\subseteq E$ then it is true. But for any $E$, you can always find an $f/g$ such that the inclusion just mentioned is true.

Comment: I see, we can always find such an $f/g$ because $K\subsetneq E \subseteq K(x)$. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to solve this problem. Let $f(x)/g(x)\in
\mathbb{E}\setminus \mathbb{K}$. Since we know that $x$ is algebaic over $\mathbb{K}(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})$, where $f(x),g(x) \in
\mathbb{K}[x]$ and $\gcd(f,g)=1$. Since $\mathbb{E}\ne \mathbb{K}$, therefore $f/g \notin \mathbb{K}$. Therefore, we have the following inclusion $\mathbb{K}\subseteq \mathbb{\mathbb{K}}(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})\subseteq \mathbb{E}\subseteq \mathbb{K}(x)$, then
$$[\mathbb{K}(x):\mathbb{E}][\mathbb{E}:\mathbb{K}(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})]=[\mathbb{K}(x):\mathbb{K}(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})]< \infty$$ implies that $[\mathbb{K}(x):\mathbb{E}]$ is finite.